# Where is the Public Key in the .NET RSA encryption

Tags: c#, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Regarding this sample: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Where in this sample is the public key used to encrypt the data?

Is it inside the RSAParameters object?

If yes what is the correct byte array to base64encode it and put the string into a web.config to re-use the public key when I have to decrypt the formerly encrypted data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you read the article you provided the link to then you will see the example says

```
    //Export the key information to an RSAParameters object.
    //Pass false to export the public key information or pass
    //true to export public and private key information.
    RSAParameters RSAParams = RSA.ExportParameters(false);
```

not sure how well you understand Public Key encyption but you use the public key to encrypt data and the private key to decrypt it so you need to ensure that the private key is stored securely, config files are not secure

you can read about the parameters here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I expected the pub/prv key to be kind of a string not RSAParameters. How should I use that parameters to get a string which I can embed as resource or save somewhere?

Comment: if you check the link i posed you will see that RSAParameters  uses the SerializableAttribute this means that you can use any serialiser to write it to a data store https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx has an example of how to serialise to a binary file. but if you swap the file stream for a memory stream you can then read it out with a stream reader into a string variable https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I want to embed it inside an assembly. Thus I created a string resouce with a key/value pair with setting embeded resouce. You think thats fine?

Comment: as long as you aren't needing to meet any security regulations that should be ok but be very sure the security on your web config means that its not visible to anyone who shouldn't have. if you are needing to meet any regs then i would suggest using the web servers certificate store as your storage that's what they are created for

Comment: "...not sure how well you understand Public Key encyption..." I looked for a string key;-)